# Slicing text with struct

Tags: c++

The file `s_file` contains a number which is the following one: 131071.That is equal to 0b000000011111111111111111.

The aim is to set the first 8 bits to the variable data->id, while setting the rest (16 bits) to the variable data->x_data. But when I print the the id and the x_data the result is the following one:

data id: 1

data x_data: 12337

Some help would be appreciated.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

typedef struct st_payload_t{
  uint8_t id;
  uint16_t x_data;
}sf_payload_t;

int main() {

    ifstream file;

    file.open("s_file", ios::binary|ios::in);
    if( file.is_open()){
      uint8_t payload[200]={0,};
      file.seekg( 0, file.beg); // Possition 0 at the relative beginning of the file
      file >> payload;
      sf_payload_t* data_1 = (sf_payload_t*) &payload[0];

      std::cout << "data id: "<<data_1->id<< std::endl;// 00000001 bin - > 1 dec
      std::cout << "data x_data: "<<data_1->x_data<< std::endl;// Should be 1111111111111111 bin - > 65535 dec

    }
    else{
      std::cout << "Not reading" << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1048575` seems to be too large for 16 bits (`uint16_t`).

Comment: `operator >>` is meant to be used with formatted data, not raw binary. Is there some reason you have to fill a buffer then do pointer casting? I think I would just create a `sf_payload_t` object then use `file.read` on each member variable.